# How can I check that frustum culling is working as expected in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to debug a few performance issues with my complex Three.js scene and I'm curious to know how I can find out whether frustum culling is working as expected.

As it stands, I'm getting bad FPS even when I zoom in and only have a few objects visible. I'm trying to work out why that is, as it should be 60fps if the objects outside of view aren't being considered.

I suppose what I'm looking for is a way to find out the number of objects being rendered each frame (and any other useful metrics) so I can see how that changes as I zoom in / force objects out of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try plotting `renderer.info.render`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a go. I'm also beginning to wonder if me using a giant merged geometry will prevent the individual elements within it from being culled as you zoom into that merged geometry.

Comment: If the geometry is all in one it's only one object that can be culled. If the object is visible it won't be culled... :)

Comment: That's cleared things up, and confirmed my suspicions. If I split my objects up into a few smaller merged geometries then it should cull correctly.